# Looking for advice to analyse this particular objective and data in R

Tags: r, data-science

*Thank you in advance for any assistance.*

**Aim:** I have a 5-day food intake survey dataset that I am trying to analyse in R. I am interested in calculating the mean, se, min and max intake for the weight of a specific food consumed per day.
I would more easily complete this in excel, but due to the scale of data, I require R to complete this.

**Example question:** What is a person's daily intake (g) of lettuce? [mean, standard deviation, standard error, min, and max]

**Example extraction dataset:** please note the actual dataset includes a number of foods and a large no. of participants.

| participant | day | code | foodname | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 1 | 62 | lettuce | 53 |
| 84 | 3 | 62 | lettuce | 23 |
| 132 | 3 | 62 | lettuce | 32 |
| 153 | 4 | 62 | lettuce | 26 |
| 142 | 2 | 62 | lettuce | 23 |
| 123 | 3 | 62 | lettuce | 23 |
| 131 | 3 | 62 | lettuce | 30 |
| 153 | 5 | 62 | lettuce | 16 |

**At present:**

```
# import dataset
foodsurvey<-read.spss("foodsurvey.sav",to.data.frame=T,use.value.labels=T)
summary(foodsurvey)

# keep my relevant columns
myvariables = subset(food survey, select = c(1,2,3,4,5) )

# rename columns
colnames(myvariables)<-c('participant','day','code','foodname','foodweight')

# create values
day<-myvariables$day
participant<-myvariables$participant
foodcode<-myvariables$foodcode
foodname<-myvariables$foodname
foodweight<-myvariables$foodweight

# extract lettuce by ID code to be analysed
lettuce<- filter(myvariables, foodcode == "62")
dim(lettuce)
str(lettuce)

# errors arise attempting to analyse consumption (weight) of lettuce per day using ops.factor function

# to analyse the outputs
summary(lettuce/days)
quantile(lettuce/foodweight)
max(lettuce)
min(lettuce)
median(lettuce)
mean(lettuce)
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: apologies, I have updated this now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should give you the mean, standard deviation, standard error, min, and max
food weight for each participant and food type combinantion along these days:

```
library(dplyr)

myvariables %>%
        filter(foodname == "lettuce") %>%
        group_by(participant) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(foodweight, na.rm = T),
                  max_val = max(foodweight),
                  min_val = min(foodweight),
                  sd = sd(foodweight, na.rm = T),
                  se = sqrt(var(foodweight, na.rm = T)/length(foodweight))
```

Comment: Lucca, thank you for this comment. May I ask - for a specific food within this foodname column (e.g. lettuce) or foodcode column(62), how may I specify this within this code?

Comment: You can add a filter() inside the pipe. I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that groups by `participant` and food itself to give summaries across everything.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(participant, foodname) %>%
  summarize(
    across(weight, list(min = min, mean = mean, max = max, 
                        sigma = sd, se = ~ sd(.)/n()))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#   participant foodname weight_min weight_mean weight_max weight_sigma weight_se
#         <int> <chr>         <int>       <dbl>      <int>        <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1          84 lettuce          23        23           23        NA        NA   
# 2         123 lettuce          23        23           23        NA        NA   
# 3         131 lettuce          30        30           30        NA        NA   
# 4         132 lettuce          32        42.5         53        14.8       7.42
# 5         142 lettuce          23        23           23        NA        NA   
# 6         153 lettuce          16        21           26         7.07      3.54
```

Once you have those summaries, you can easily filter for one participant, a specific food, etc. If you need to also group by `code`, just add it to the `group_by`.

The premise of using `summarise(across(...))` is that the first argument includes whichever variables you want to summarize (just `weight` here, but you can add others if it makes sense), and the second argument is a list of functions in various forms. It accepts just a function symbol (e.g., `mean`), a tilde-function facilitate by `rlang` (e.g., `~ sd(.) / n()`, where `n()` is a dplyr-special function), or regular anonymous functions (e.g., `function(z) sd(z)/length(z)`, not shown here). The "name" on the LHS of each listed function is used in the resulting column name.

Comment: Hi r2evans, for some reason this does not seem to generate any nibble outputs for me, do you advise any way to call this from the console?

Comment: output in console: Error in base::nchar(wide_chars$test, type = "width") : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?